# Why are i.e. and e.g. abbreviated with periods between each word and etc. not?

Tags: abbreviations, latin

Why are *i.e.* (*id est*) and *e.g.* (*exempli gratia*) abbreviated with periods between each word and *etc.* (*et cetera*) not abbreviated as *et.c.*?

Comment: *et* isn't abbreviated is it?

Comment: @Jim are you asking why the last _et_ is not abbreviated?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the original abbreviation of the phrase "et cetera" was "&c.", and in fact the ampersand existed as a common "letter" in English for quite some time.  Instead of referring back to the original Latin, when ampersands fell out of use "&c." turned into "etc.".

Comment: Plus, "etcetera" (with no blank) is a common (since 1597) English spelling.